# Flutter, I get an error when using CupertinoTabScaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

```
CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            label: '',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
         switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: Categories(), );
            });
           case 1:
            return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: FavPage(), );
            }); 
            case 2:
            return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: Cart(), );
            }); 
            default:
            return CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return const CupertinoPageScaffold(
                child: Categories(), );
            });             
        }
      }, 
    );
```

error message:

> Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/categoryDetails", GzE5usW4fApu38pjA) in the_CupertinoTabViewState.

when I click on a category in the "Categories" screen it has to navigate to "CategoryDetails" screen

Comment: did you define this "/categoryDetails" route in MaterialApp's routes list?

Comment: `return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const SplashScreen(),
        '/categories': (context) => const CustomBottomNB(),       
        '/categoryDetails' :(context) => const CategoryDetails(),
        '/productdetail': (context) => const Product(),
      },
    );`

Comment: that's how I defined /categoryDetails

Comment: and how did you navigate to /categoryDetails?

Comment: when I am in "categories" screen, I can navigate to "categoryDetails".

Comment: instead of navigate with push name try this: Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) =>
     new CategoryDetails())
  );

Comment: No dear, I have to use pushNamed because I need to pass the argument (id of category) in the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it

```dart
CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
            label: '',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        assert(index >= 0 && index <= 2);
         switch (index) {
          case 0:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => Categories(),,
            );
            break;
          
           case 1:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => FavPage(),
            );
            break;
          
            case 2:
            return CupertinoTabView(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => Cart(),
            );
            break;
          }
             return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => Categories(),
        );             
        }
      }, 
    );
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, sorry same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use as **routes** or **onGenererateRoutes** according to your requirements in TabViewState of CuptinoTabBar.

Something like this...

```
return CupertinoTabView(
      routes: appRoutes,
//or
      onGenerateRoutes: ...,
```